# Scroll Background Like Lunar Lander or Ninja Jump Game - Android

Tags: android, game-physics, 2d-games

I'm developing a 2d Game using Canvas/Surfaceview and have a problem with scrolling my background image.

Check out the game - http://youtu.be/4Gi5rRqzZ3M

In the NinJump game, the character Ninja is just jumping in X coordinates and Background image is scrolling at a very high speed, making Ninja look like it is actually running.

I have created the basic setup, created the Ninja, added jump functionality, added background. **Now I want to repeat the same background over and over again. How can I accomplish that?**

Below are my source files - Main Activity Class

```
    package com.abc.apps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class LadderActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = LadderActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // requesting to turn the title OFF
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // set our MainGamePanel as the View
        setContentView(new MainGameBoard(this));
        Log.d(TAG, "View added"); 
    }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
     Log.d(TAG, "Destroying...");
     super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
     Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
     super.onStop();
 }
}
```

**Game Board extends SurfaceView**

```
    package com.abc.apps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MainGameBoard extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private MainGameLoop thread;
    private Monkey monkey;
    private static final String TAG = MainGameLoop.class.getSimpleName();

    int currentX, currentY;


    public MainGameBoard(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
        //This line sets the current class (MainGamePanel) as the handler for the events happening on the actual surface
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // create monkey and load bitmap INITIALIZE AT LEFT
        monkey = new Monkey(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.actor),60, 340); 

        // create the game loop thread
        thread = new MainGameLoop(getHolder(), this);


        // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events.
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
        // this is a clean shutdown
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
               } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // try again shutting down the thread
               }
              }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             //For jumping Left
             if (event.getX() < (getWidth()/2 - 32)) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
                 //Log.d(TAG, "Jump Left");
                // Sleep so that the main thread doesn't get flooded with UI events.
                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(32);
                     monkey.setX((getWidth()/2 - 60));
                     monkey.setY(monkey.getY()-70);

                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // No big deal if this sleep is interrupted.
                 }


             }

             //For Jumping Right
             if (event.getX() > (getWidth()/2 + 32)) {
                 //Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
                 //Log.d(TAG, "Jump Right");
                // Sleep so that the main thread doesn't get flooded with UI events.
                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(32);

                     monkey.setX((getWidth()/2 + 60));
                     monkey.setY(monkey.getY()-70); 

                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // No big deal if this sleep is interrupted.
                 }


             }

/*           //Middle Portion
             if (event.getX() > (getWidth()/2 - 32) && event.getX() < (getWidth()/2 +32)) {
                 //thread.setRunning(false);
                 //((Activity)getContext()).finish();
             }*/


         }
         return true;
        }



    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.monkey_sc), 0, 0,null);
        monkey.draw(canvas);
    }

/*  @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.monkey_scene), 0, 0,null);
        monkey.draw(canvas);
    }*/



}
```

**Main Game Loop**

```
package com.abc.apps;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainGameLoop extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private MainGameBoard gameBoard;
    private Monkey monkey;

    private static final String TAG = MainGameLoop.class.getSimpleName();

    // flag to hold game state
    private boolean running = true;



    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
        }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
         Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
          while (running) {

              canvas = null;    
              // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing on the surface
              try {
                  canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                  synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        // update game state 
                        // render state to the screen
                        // draws the canvas on the panel
                        gameBoard.render(canvas);   
                    }
              } 
              finally {
                  // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
                  // an inconsistent state
                  if (canvas != null) {
                      surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                } // end finally
            }
        } 




    public MainGameLoop(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGameBoard gameBoard) {
     super();
     this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
     this.gameBoard = gameBoard;
    }



}//MainThread
```

**Monkey Class**

```
package com.abc.apps;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class Monkey {

 private Bitmap bitmap; // the actual bitmap
 private int x;   // the X coordinate
 private int y;   // the Y coordinate
 private boolean touched; // if monkey is touched


 public Monkey(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
  this.bitmap = bitmap;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

 }

 public Bitmap getBitmap() {
  return bitmap;
 } 
 public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
  this.bitmap = bitmap;
 }
 public int getX() {
  return x;
 }
 public void setX(int x) {
  this.x = x;
 }
 public int getY() {
  return y;
 }
 public void setY(int y) {
  this.y = y;
 }

 public boolean isTouched() {
  return touched;
 }

 public void setTouched(boolean touched) {
  this.touched = touched;
 }


 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
     Paint paint = new Paint();
     paint.setAntiAlias(true);
     paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
     paint.setDither(true);

  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), y, paint);
 }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are drawing your background in your MainGameBoard class in the render method.

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.monkey_sc), 0, 0,null);

monkey.draw(canvas);
}
```

You should just need 2 drawBitmap calls instead of 1 there.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.monkey_sc), 0, y_offset1,null);
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.monkey_sc), 0, y_offset2,null);
```

I'm making an assumption that each background image has the same height or greater than the screen height; if it is less than the screen height you would need more than 2 instances.

Then you start 1 image at y_offset1 = 0 and the other at y_offset2 = -image_height.

Each draw you would increase y_offset1 and y_offset2 by the same amount.  You would then need to do a check for both offsets to see if either has an amount greater than the screen height.  If it does then the y_offset that is now "below screen" should be reset to the other y_offset minus the image_height.  This will create a scroll image that loops indefinitely.

When using this type of technique it is important to think about your image edges; the image should be designed such that they tile seamlessly, otherwise at the looping point there is a noticeable visual artifact along the edge.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail as to where should i code... I am a newbiew in android. I also believe that FPS factor has to be involved

Comment: I don't have that but I have added all the source code in the original post itself. For background image I am usin a simple white background.

Comment: I am really fed up, if someone has time then can any one make a working tutorial